# How do I see what updates are a available in the terminal

Tags: 16.04, server, updates, security

I have a server running Ubuntu 16,  how do I find out what are the security updates and apply them?

**How to choose the ones I want?**

How do I know if they will not interfere with running app?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You can run

```
sudo apt update && apt list --upgradable
```

That will first update the package list and then show available upgrades.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update        # Fetches the list of available updates
sudo apt-get upgrade       # Strictly upgrades the current packages
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  # Installs updates (new ones)
```

If you want to see the sources where your updated are coming from run the following:

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Alternatively, under Ubuntu, open the Ubuntu Software Center and click the Updates tab, and it will display everything that can be updated inside the GUI.